# Working In App purchase app suddenly stopped working .In App purchase popup is not coming

Tags: ios, xamarin.forms, in-app-purchase, apple-developer

3 months back i have uploaded the ios app on apple developer account which have In App purchase functionality .But from last 15 days "Confirm In App purchase" option is not coming in any of the ios device. Thanks in advance .[This pop up is not appearing after purchase button click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FxmPE.png)

Comment: Please add some code so other users can test what you're describing. Thanks!

Comment: @IgnacioAra From last 3 months In App purchase is working fine .But from last 15 days on click of Purchase button "Confirm In App Purchase " Popup is not coming in any  of the ios devices .